# Trigonometric Functions: sine equal at three points.

Tags: trigonometry

What is the characterization of $\omega$ and $\phi$ so that $\sin(\omega t_1+\phi)=\sin(\omega t_2+\phi)=\sin(\omega t_3+\phi)$ for three arbitrary $t_1<t_2<t_3$? Thanks!

---

I have tried to use that $\sin(A+B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)+\sin(B)\cos(A)$ in each of the three expressions, reducing the problem to two implicit equations in $\phi$, $\omega$. One of the resulting equations contains $\omega$ only, in terms $\sin(\omega tj)$ and $\cos(\omega tj)$ for $j=1,2,3$ and no $\phi$. So one can, in principle, solve for $\omega$ using this equation. The other equation contains a similar expression on ω and the ratio $\cos(\phi)/\sin(\phi)$. One can obtain $\phi$ from the second equation, given $\omega$. Yet the expressions don't suggest a clear characterization to me.

Comment: I have tried to use that $\sin(A+B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)+\sin(B)\cos(A)$ in each of the three expressions, reducing the problem to two implicit equations in $\phi,\omega$.

One of the resulting equations contains $\omega$ only, in terms  $\sin(\omega t_j)$ \& $ \cos(\omega t_j)$ for $ j=1,2,3$ and no $\phi$. So one can, in principle, solve for $\omega$ using this eqn.

The other equation contains a similar expression on $\omega$ and the ratio $\cos(\phi)/\sin(\phi)$. One ca obtain $\phi$ from the second eqn, given $\omega$. 

Yet the expressions don't suggest a clear characterization to me.

Comment: @Fernando Alvarez. Only for advice : Already two people voted to close your question, probably because the wording of the question infringes the rules of StackExchange. In response, you wrote a comment. That is well, but this doesn't correct the wording of the question, which continue to infringe the rules because the wording remains the same as before. To avoid more down votes, better improve your question itself instead of comment. Use the ''Edit'' button below your question.

Comment: Thanks, I would, I should read the rules again.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $\omega=0$ is a trivial case. If not, it must hold that either $$\omega t_i+\phi=\omega t_j+\phi+2k\pi\quad,\quad 1\le i\ne j\le 3$$(which doesn't hold) or $$\omega t_i+\phi=2k\pi +\pi-\omega t_j-\phi\quad,\quad 1\le i\ne j\le 3$$ which also doesn't hold. Therefore the case where $\omega=0$ is the only case

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am sorry the question was not clearly stated.

Comment: It's OK........